# extract and log a value from JSON data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yahoo-pipes

I have searched and searched but being unsure how to phrase my queries I have been unable to achieve what i believe is a simple goal.

I have an RSS feed from Deviant Art that is run through Yahoo Pipes

this is the pipe"
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=63478be58fb00758ded9d5108170f931

the JSON the pipe produces 
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=63478be58fb00758ded9d5108170f931&_render=json
looks like this:

`{"url":"http:\/\/darksilverflame.deviantart.com","content":"Copyright 2012 *DarkSilverflame","description":null,"title":null},`........

What I am trying to achieve is a simple way of parsing the data via jquery(or just JS) and then generating a simple txt list of usernames from the Deviant Art and the links to those users pages.

Comment: You are lacking quite a bit of important info my friend. Most specifically, what language are you using?

Comment: sorry, thanks for the alert, I've updated the question. I am very new here and trying to learn javascript. I am using either javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

jQuery.parseJSON( json ) [Link to jQuery Documentaion](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
parsedObject =jQuery.parseJSON( '{"url":"http:\/\/darksilverflame.deviantart.com","content":"Copyright 2012 *DarkSilverflame","description":null,"title":null}');
```

or form Chrome (F12 -> Console then test the folowing)

```
  a = JSON.parse('{"url":"http:\/\/darksilverflame.deviantart.com","content":"Copyright 2012 *DarkSilverflame","description":null,"title":null}');
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To further on Mehdi's answer:  if you are looking for a simple way to retrieve and process the data in one step, you can start with the usual incantation:

$.getJSON('http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=63478be58fb00758ded9d5108170f931&_render=json',
            function(data){
                 $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                        // do something here
                 }
            }
);

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON